# My java program won't import a text file

Tags: java, arrays, import, records

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class RacecarTimes
{
    int carNumber, trackDistance;
    String track;
    double time;
}

public class main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new java.io.File("racecartimes.txt"));

            RacecarTimes[] data = new RacecarTimes[10];
            int numRecords, i = 0, a = 1;

            while (inFile.hasNext() && i < data.length)
            {
                    RacecarTimes n = new RacecarTimes();
                    n.carNumber = inFile.nextInt();
                    n.trackDistance = inFile.nextInt();
                    n.track = inFile.nextLine();
                    n.time = inFile.nextDouble();
                    data[i] = n;
                    i++;
            }
            inFile.close();
            numRecords = i;

            System.out.println(numRecords + " race times loaded.");

            int fastest = data[0].carNumber;
            double fastestTime = data[0].trackDistance/data[0].time;

            while (a < numRecords)
            {
                    if ((data[a].trackDistance/data[a].time) < fastestTime)
                    {
                            fastestTime = data[a].trackDistance/data[a].time;
                            fastest = data[a].carNumber;
                            a++;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                            a++;
                            continue;
                    }
            }

            for(int q = 0; q < numRecords; q++)
            {
                    System.out.println("Car: " + data[q].carNumber);
                    System.out.println("Track: " + data[q].track);
                    System.out.println("Track Distance: " + data[q].trackDistance);
                    System.out.println("Time: " + data[q].time + "\n");
            }

            System.out.println("Fastest time: " + fastestTime + "m/s");
            System.out.println("Fastest Car Number: " + fastest);

        }
}
```

This is a school assignment so it meets all the requirements of the assignment, I just need to get it working. I have a text file in the same directory as the java class named "racecartimes.txt" and for some reason I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at AndrewLaramore56.main(AndrewLaramore56.java:40)
```

The program should import the racecar information from the text file and then spit it back out along with the fastest time/car.

I am not sure what is going wrong or how to fix it. Do I need to have the full address of the file in java.io.File()? I am going off of what my textbook is telling me to do so it might be wrong as well.

Answer (score 0):

The file has been found, otherwise you would get a `FileNotFoundException`. It looks like the exception is thrown on `n.carNumber = inFile.nextInt();` because the data that is read in is not a valid `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if your `Scanner` has another input token, but not what type it is.  Also, you are trying to pull multiple tokens out after only having checked for the existence of one:

```
while (inFile.hasNext() && i < data.length)  // there exists at least one token
{
    RacecarTimes n = new RacecarTimes();
    n.carNumber = inFile.nextInt();          // what if the next token is not an int?
    n.trackDistance = inFile.nextInt();      // you haven't checked for this token at all
    n.track = inFile.nextLine();             // etc
    n.time = inFile.nextDouble();
```

You need to check for each piece of data individually, to verify that it's the correct type, and also that there is still more data to read:

```
while (inFile.hasNext() && i < data.length)
{
    RacecarTimes n = new RacecarTimes();
    if (inFile.hasNextInt()) {
        n.carNumber = inFile.nextInt();
    }
    if (inFile.hasNextInt()) {
        n.trackDistance = inFile.nextInt();
    }
    // etc
```

Comment: So I added the if statements and that allowed it to give me output, but it seems not all of the numbers are ints. What makes a number an int?

Comment: @thepinkanator95  In Java an `int` is an integral number from -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive. If it's outside of that range, but still between -9223372036854775808 and 9223372036854775807 you can use a `long`.  If you provide a sample of your input I can be more specific about what type(s) to use to store it.

Comment: `14
2478
45
Atlanta Motor Speedway
45
3218
62
Auto Club Speedway
24
853
26
Bristol Motor Speedway`
This is my input text file.

Comment: So your data is `number number number trackname`, but you are trying to read `int int string double`.  It looks like you are trying to parse `Atlanta Motor Speedway` as a `double`, and so on.

Comment: Stupid mistake. Now, though, it still won't import everything. It seems to be loading every other piece of data into a new record (so the first one will print car number and track name and the second will have the distance and time of the first etc.).